# How Android app install tracking works?

Tags: android, installation, tracking

can anybody here  explain how android app referral tracking works? a friend gave me an android app's google play referral url. And i installed the app and opened it. How does the app developer know that it's my friend who referred me to their app? I know that the link that my friend gave me contains his referral details but if i close google play after completing the app install, how can google play detect that i opened the app? So some unique data is injected into the app while i install it from playstore. am i right? Please explain.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's quite simple actually. You click on the link with a referral (Google calls them *Campaing Attribution*) and this link is passed to the Google Play Store app. Then, when you install the app, the Play Store also forwards this data (campaign name, source, &c) *to the app itself*.

The app just needs to have a particular `BroadcastReceiver` (with an `intent-filter` for the  `com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER` action) declared in its Manifest for this to work.

It's well explained in the [Google Play Campaign Attribution](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-campaigns) section of the Google Analytics documentation.

Comment: i understand that. my main doubt is in the second part of the question. how does the app developer detect that i opened the app after install so that my friend will get my referral? there is some unique data inside the installed app so that the app can verify that i've opened and used the app?

Comment: The BroadcastReceiver gets all the data from the link. It can then store it locally, if it wants, or (more likely) forward it to google analytics. So, in short, yes.

Comment: so like i said earlier, while i install the app, it installs some unique data with the app which can track me(or my friend's referral) and when i open the app, that data will be send to google analytics to make sure that i opened an used the app?

Comment: It's not that it "installs some unique data" -- it rather executes whatever code the app developer signaled he wanted to be executed (the BroadcastReceiver), _passing the data as input_. Then the app can store it, send to the server, or do whatever else it wants with it.

Comment: So my doubt is that, something unique(so that it can identify my friend) is installed with the app. right?

Comment: The referrer link has some data. If it was created specifically for your friend then yes, it identifies him.

Comment: yes. the referral link varies according to users and my friend got a unique link. so, after i install via his link, something that identifies him will be stored inside the installed app. right? i understand the referral code entering method but this makes confusion.

Comment: All the fields from the referral link are passed to the app. Whether it stores them or not, is up to the app -- it can execute whatever id was programmed to do with this information. I don't know how to explain this more clearly :(

Comment: yeah. now i understand. i was asking this from the beginning and it was my doubt. thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @user3548321 Hi i am just developing same application, but I can not succeded, can you please help me with some example code? It will be a great pleasure.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example how you can implement a custom BroadcastReceiver with INSTALL_REFERRER.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".CustomInstallTrackersReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

ManyInstallTrackersReceiver.java

```
import com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.InstallReferrerReceiver;

public class CustomInstallTrackersReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            // Implementing Google Referrer tracker
            InstallReferrerReceiver googleReferrerTracking = new InstallReferrerReceiver();
            googleReferrerTracking.onReceive(context, intent);

            // Do something with referrer data to do your own tracker.
            Log.d("CustomInstallTrackers", "Referrer: "+intent.getStringExtra("referrer"));
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You can test it with the following commands

```
$ adb shell
$ am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n com.your.package/com.your.package.CustomInstallTrackersReceiver --es "referrer" "hello%3Dworld%26utm_source%3Dshell"
```

Answer (score 0):

**From 20 November 2017**, Its very simple using **[Google Play Referrer API](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/google-play-referrer-api-track-and.html)**