# Track the user who shared my app and who installed

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play-services, referrer

I have a problem: I have an app that I want to know who is partnering who installed from that user who shared it. I saw something like referrer / UTM, which reads the parameters sent by the Play Store, but I can not implement it in IONIC.

The idea is to know who shared and who installed from that shared.

Does anyone have a tutorial or a tip on what to look for?

thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-campaigns) to help you start with.

> This document provides an overview of how to measure campaigns and
>   traffic sources with the Google Analytics SDK v4 for Android.

It was mentioned in the [Overview](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#overview) section about the function you need.

> Measuring campaigns in Google Analytics enables the attribution of
>   campaigns and traffic sources to user activity within your
>   application. These options are available for campaign and traffic
>   source attribution in the Google Analytics SDK v4 for Android:
>
> 1. [Google Play Campaign Attribution](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-campaigns) - **See which campaigns,
>      websites, and other apps are referring users to Google Play Store to
>      download your app.**
> 2. [General Campaign & Traffic Source Attribution](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#general-campaigns) - See which
>      campaigns or referrers launch your app after it is installed.

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226895/how-android-app-install-tracking-works) maybe could help you.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to develop these documents